# Extract Data From Column That Contains List and Record Types

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, data-cleaning, m

I have a column in a table that contains both List and Record data types. How can I convert the Records into a list type so the column is consistent to the point where I can easily convert it into a single column with each record separated by commas?

| ShareRoot.Access |
| --- |
| List |
| List |
| Record |
| List |
| Record |

The List types look similar to the following:
[image: List]

And the record looks similar to this:
[image: Record]

Comment: Have you tried using the `Record.ToList` method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/record-tolist

Comment: @B.Griffin I've tried, but I wasn't able to get it to work without errors. To be honest, I'm not very familiar with M, so I've been doing a lot of trial and error and have gotten stuck...

Comment: Could you provide the full M query that you attempted? And some details of the errors you got would also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom column and build up the string like this (first part provided but you can do the rest)

```
if Value.Is([ShareRoot.Access], List.Type) then [ShareRoot.Access]  else {"@FileSystemRights="& Record.Field([ShareRoot.Access], "FileSystemRights")}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this thanks to @Davide Bacci. I also ended up not using a comma delimiter since I will still be able to parse the output easily.

```
if Value.Is([ShareRoot.Access], List.Type) then Text.Combine([ShareRoot.Access], "") else Text.Combine({"@{FileSystemRights=" & Number.ToText(Record.Field([ShareRoot.Access], "FileSystemRights")), "; AccessControlType=" & Number.ToText(Record.Field([ShareRoot.Access], "AccessControlType")), "; IdentityReference=" & Record.Field([ShareRoot.Access], "IdentityReference"), "}"})
```